# How to change column value by matching row value in data frame?

Tags: python, data-frame, geodataframe

Say I do have the following table

```
| longitude | latitude | temperature | label |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-------|
|     x     |    y     |       z     |     1 |
|     p     |    q     |       r     |     2 |
|     a     |    b     |       c     |     1 |
|     k     |    l     |       m     |     1 |
```

I store the table in df and run the following data fragment query.

`df1= df.query('longitude == @x and latitude == @y and temperature== @z')`

Mostly I am getting the correct output.

Now I want to change the label value for my row matched by the query

`df.query('longitude == a and latitude == b and temperature== c')`

How can I update the label value matched by the query row. I tried using .replace , .iloc but None of them is giving me proper result.

Comment: What spatial Python library have you imported before getting to the lines of code that you have presented?

Comment: Why x,y,z and other values are strings and what are the @x,@y and @z values ?

Comment: And where is the GIS component of the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mask`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "longitude": ["x", "p", "a", "k"],
        "latitude": ["y", "q", "b", "l"],
        "temperature": ["z", "r", "c", "m"],
        "label": [1, 2, 1, 1],
    }
)

new_label = 3

df["label"] = df["label"].mask(
    (df["longitude"] == "a") & (df["latitude"] == "b") & (df["temperature"] == "c"),
    new_label,
)
df
```

[image: pandas dataframe]

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. It helped a lot in finishing my coding where I was stuck for more than six months. It is a big help for me.

Comment: @Teacher If answer helped you, it would be appropriate from your side to at least upvote, id not accept it.